# Is there any C function that returns constant variable name for a given input value?

Tags: c, macros

For example lets say I defined a constant as below using #define macro in C

```
#define MAXSIZE 10
```

Is there any function in C that I can invoke by passing 10 as input and retrieve that constant name "MAXSIZE". Thanks

Comment: There's no function in the standard library to do that, no.

Comment: It would not be possible to write a function to do this as `#define` is a preprocessor directive, meaning that by the time we get to runtime, it is gone

Comment: Is the the question just out of curiosity? If not, describe the actual problem you try to solve so we can give good advice.

Answer (score 5):

No for many reasons:

- C is not a reflective language
- what if there are several constants with the same `10` value?

but the actual reason that kills it is:

- preprocessor actually replaces `MAXSIZE` by `10` *before* compiling, so this information is lost

Comment: C has no built-in facility for this, but you can write your own function to do as the OP asks, subject to some non-trivial limitations (among them that such a function can support at most one macro name for any given value).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, the c preprocessor replaces all occurences of MAXSIZE with 10 when run.

Comment: The answer is C has no *built-in* facility for it, but you can roll your own, subject to some non-trivial limitations.